# Dynamically change colors of navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css, sencha-touch-2

in a sencha touch 2 application, I am using a navigation bar

```
var homeNavigation = {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype : 'homeView',
    config : {
        autoDestroy: false,
        iconCls : 'homeicon',
        title : 'Home',
        navigationBar: {
            items: [
                myInfoButton,
                addButton
            ]
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype : 'homeIndexView'
            }
        ]

    }
};

Ext.define('MyAPP.view.Home', homeNavigation);
```

I need to change it's color to a red gradient.

For that I done the following is the css sheet:

```
.x-toolbar-dar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #5a000b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #b98182), color-stop(50%, #781a2c), color-stop(51%, #5a000b), color-stop(100%, #4a020e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b98182, #781a2c 50%, #5a000b 51%, #4a020e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #b98182, #781a2c 50%, #5a000b 51%, #4a020e);
  border-color: #4a020e;
}
```

it is working correctly and the navigation bar has the wanted color.

**The problem**

I need to change it's color dynamicallym this is where I am having problems. I need to checge it's color when a view is pushed in the navigation

In the controller I have created this function:

```
applyThemeToNavigationBar : function() {
                        $(".x-toolbar-dark").css({
                            "backgroundImage": "none",
                            "backgroundColor": "#5a000b",
                            "backgroundImage": "-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #b98182), color-stop(50%, #781a2c), color-stop(51%, #5a000b), color-stop(100%, #4a020e))",
                            "backgroundImage": "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b98182, #781a2c 50%, #5a000b 51%, #4a020e)",
                            "backgroundImage": "linear-gradient(top, #b98182, #781a2c 50%, #5a000b 51%, #4a020e)",
                            "backgroundColor": "#4a020e"
                        });

                }
```

And in the push event of a view : `push : 'onViewPush'` I call the above function to change the CSS:

```
onViewPush: function(view, item) {
                    applyThemeToNavigationBar();
                    alert('theme changed');
                }
```

The alert('them changed') is being called when the view is pushed but the navigation view is not changing colors.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where does this $ come from? Do you also have jQuery ? Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes I have Jquery and use it normally. No errors in the console. And it I try to alert `$(".x-toolbar-dark").length` I get 5 which means that the object is defined and not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since toolbar is also a Component you should be able to use [addCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-addCls) & [removeCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-removeCls) to change its cls attribute to whichever CSS class you want.